# Как пишутся слова "всемогущественный" и "всерешающий"?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется *всемогущественный* и *всерешающий*?

Answer (score 2):

1) Слово ***всемогущественный*** пишется слитно

Все — первая часть сложных слов. 1. Вносит зн.: охватывающий всё и всех, распространяющийся на всё и на всех: всепланетный, всепобеждающий.  2. Обозначает самую высокую степень проявления, исчерпывающую полноту признака, обозначенного во второй части слова: всецело. 3. Обозначает пригодность для условий любого типа: всепогодный, вседорожный.

2) Словосочетание ***всё решающий*** пишется раздельно

Например: *всё решающий* случай, *всё решающее* время.

Есть игра Годвилль, где используется словосочетание "**бог все решающий**" с раздельным написанием. Это окказионализм (лингв., слово, образованное по непродуктивной модели или употреблённое применительно к данному контексту). При этом слово *всерешающий* нужно писать слитно, в то время как **всё решающий**  пишется раздельно. [Бог Все решающий и его герой | godville.net](https://godville.net/gods/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9)